# iPhone Predicate error Can't use in/contains operator with collection in search

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

For a search bar of contacts I am using an `NSPredicate` to filter results.  I have used the exact same code on other entities without an issue.  However, when I use it on this one entity, it returns the error:

> Can't use in/contains operator with collection FIRST (not a collection)

Here is the code.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [getContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Not all the records have first which refers to first name.  Could it be that null values for first are causing the error?  If so, how would I allow for null values?

Alternatively, what else could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like FIRST is being interpreted as an aggregate operation. Try changing it to firstName. This will make it clearer for coredata and also your future self (some time in the future you may add an address with firstLine for street address which could be confusing)

Comment: This makes sense, however, I also get error if I search on fields such as co or descript

Comment: Turns out co and descript were giving errors for different reason.  But last also gives same error as first.  Would it make sense that LAST is also a defined term?

Comment: Yes. Last is also an aggregate operation. Have a look here. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Ok.  Guess I wil have to go through the laborious process of changing attribute names throughout code.  Or maybe I will set up special attributes for searching.